how AI will analyze Tactical Insights of players in this platform
I am not able to find the answer of this question that is the issue
an answer to this issue as I am not able to find it and I want something solid, concrete. So please let me know the process of it. If you need more information I can provide that in the meantime I'll look forward to the answer
